# PHP Array Echo Not Working

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like:

```
[meta] => Array (
  [company] => Company, LLC
  [confirmation] => 6391381
  [reference] => None
  [service] => Service
  [timestamp] => 2016-04-25 11:12:54
  [user] => company
)
[result] => Array (
  [action] => REVIEW
  [detail] => TRANSACTION REQUIRES FURTHER ATTENTION
  [issues] => Array (
      [0] => DOB CHECK FAILED
    )
)
[output] =>  Array ( )
```

I am attempting to echo the 'action' value like this:

```
$json_result = json_decode($result, true); 
echo "$json_result[result]['action']";
```

But instead of getting 'REVIEW' I am getting: `'Array['action']'`

Any thoughts?

Comment: `echo $json_result['result']['action'];`?

Comment: @jon when i try it like this i get the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: The code example I gave would not produce that error, or any error assuming your question is accurate. You've used it wrong.

Comment: Yes it would (if still in double quotes). The single quoted array key inside the double quoted string is wrong. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double  To use quoted keys inside double quotes, it must be `{}` enclosed.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Do you see any double quotes in my comment?

Comment: @JonStirling No, but I was referring to your second comment ---ohhh I get the context now. The reported error was based on your unquoted example, not the original.

Comment: Here's a full explanation of the quoting rules: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/13935532#13935532

Comment: Okay, I got it!
Remove the double quotes (") from echo.

Answer (score 2):

using arrays inside strings leads to madness. or at least horrible frustration.

as Jon Stirling pointed out, in your case why even bother putting the variable in a double quote?

```
echo $json_result['result']['action'];
```

works just fine. If you *must* use an array inside a string, escape it with curly braces

```
echo "{$json_result['result']['action']}";
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the apostrophes from the first index:

```
$json_result[result]['action'];
```

It should look like this:

```
$json_result['result']['action'];
             ^      ^
```

**Edit:**
You can use regular php syntax to address array values if you put the whole expression between curly braces ( **{** ):

```
echo "This is the result: {$json_result['result']['action']};"
```

...or simply remove the double quotes (") from echo.

More info here: **[php echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)**

Answer (score 0):

To review all array

```
print_r($json_result);
```

To view only action

```
echo $json_result['result']['action'];
```

Comment: When i try it like this I get the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: @TomCanfarotta If you're getting the T_ENCAPSED AND WHITESPACE is't sbecause you still have double quotes surrounding the whole thing as `echo "$json_result['result']['action']";`  Note the example above does not have them.